# Creating Custom Action bars for each activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-activity, android-titlebar

I need to create custom title bars for each and every Screen in my android application. For an example, in GMail, Yahoo Mail android applications, have you noticed that their title bar differs from activity to activity? This is what I need.

I went through number of tutorials, unfortunatly, they are to replace the title bar of the entire application with one custom title bar.

Following is what I have tried

**Cuatom_title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bileeta_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#579bef"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
//Setting custom title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

//Set the custom title bar
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

But this just generated errors.

How can I create custom title bars for each and every activity?

Comment: use `ActionBar` in each Activity.

Comment: @Ketan: Thanks for the reply. This is my first attemt in such. Bit more information please? May be as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onCreate()`

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  //for higher version
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
 actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
```

OR

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  //to support lower version too
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
 actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the error 'The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Home' for the method 'getSupportActionBar();'

Comment: @Raghunandan:android:minSdkVersion="10"

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence action bar is available from api level 11 i guess. if you need back ward compatibility use appcompact from support library or actonbar sherlock

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks. Now it is showing. But it is "mixed" with the title

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence mixed? din't get you

Comment: @Raghunandan: Yeah, The title and the action bar, both are displayed. I don't need the title

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence if I understand you correctly you can do, `getActionBar().setTitle("");`

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, while declaring activity you can add this line `android:label="@string/your_title_string"`
Example:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/your_title_string" >            
        </activity>
```